# assign a javascript option select return value to angularjs argument

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have a function in javascript that returns a value of an option select html tag. I am trying to assign the returned value to an angularjs argument to call an api for the second drop down immediately a select drop value is selected. Here is my attempt:

this is the angularjs taking a javascript argument >>>

```
getUserDetails.getUserDetails(choice1(this))
```

here is the complete snippet

```
<select  ng-change="getUserDetails.getUserDetails(choice1(this))" ng-model="reg.country" formcontrol name="country" class="ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-valid" required>
        <option value="0: ">-Select Country-</option>

        <c:forEach var="findAllCountries" items="${findAllCountries}" varStatus="theCount">
            <option value="${findAllCountries.id}">${findAllCountries.name}</option>

        </c:forEach>

        </select>
```

javascript function

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function choice1(select) {
    return select.options[select.selectedIndex].value;
}
</script>
```

the above attempt gives me an error on trying to pass javascript return value to angularjs argument.

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: 400 Bad Request due to inability to get the returned id value as needed in the getUserDetails.getUserDetails() angularjs function